# Adding a fancy "frame" to picture

Tags: html, image, css, border

Does anyone have an idea how to convert this picture frame
[image]
into css  `box-shadow`?
If anyone has some ideas please tell me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position absolute inside a container div.
Apply CSS3 2D Transforms

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="box1"></div>

    <div class="box2"></div>

    <div class="box3"></div>

</div>


.container{
    width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
}


.box1, .box2, .box3{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 10;
}

.box1{

    transform:rotate(5deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(5deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(5deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}

.box2{

    transform:rotate(-5deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-5deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}

.box3{
    background-color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dULUp/

**Edit**

Updated JSfiddle with dropshadow:
http://jsfiddle.net/dULUp/1/

**Edit 2**
This is an overdue edit but I've been going over the answers that I've given to see how much I've progressed as a developer.

If you look at the above JSFiddle with drop shadow in Chrome you'll notice the jagged edges.

Added:

```
/* Added to remove jagged edges */
.container *{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

See working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dULUp/3/

Comment: You're very welcome, good luck with your project.